# How to separate paragraphs by using getTextRanges

Tags: office-js, cpu-word

I have two paragraphs like below. Hello and World are separated by a paragraph mark. How can I specify the endingMark in getTextRanges to get two ranges: Hello and World? getTextRanges("^13") doesn't work.

```
Hello
World
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to try with paragraph API to [getFirst](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.paragraphcollection?view=word-js-preview#getfirst--) and then [getNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=word-js-preview#getnext--) for second paragraph.

```
 await Word.run(async (context) => {
    let paragraph = context.document.body.paragraphs.getFirst();
    paragraph.load();
    await context.sync();
    console.log(paragraph.text);

    var para = paragraph.getNextOrNullObject();
    para.load();
    await context.sync();
    console.log(para.text);

  });
```

Comment: I just realized that it is not paragraph mark but a ^13 which appears when you do a manual carriage return. How can I separate sentences with ^13?

Comment: Try this. Open a Word doc. Go to File | Options and turn one Display all characters. In the Word doc, press Shift-Return to create a line break character. Copy the character and paste it as the parameter to `getTextRanges`. If that doesn't work, put square brackets, [ ], around it.